# Will Index file be updated after renaming the key variable in SAS?

Tags: indexing, sas, rename, datastep

According to [Understanding SAS Indexes](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000440261.htm)

If you rename key variable in SAS, the simple index is renamed instead of being deleted.

However, when I try this on my own, the index file will disappear after I rename the key variable, I wonder what is wrong?

Here is the code that I used:

```
data work.temp(index=(id));
input id $ amount;
cards;
p       52
p       45
a       13
a       56
r       34
r       12
r       78
;
proc contents data=work.temp;
run;

data WORK.temp ;
set WORK.temp (keep=Id amount rename=(Id=Id_Code));
run;

proc contents data=work.temp;
run;
```

You can see from the result that after renaming the key variable Id, the index disappears.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would disappear even if you didn't rename the variable.

```
data temp;
set temp;
run;
```

That destroys the index as well.  The reason is that the Data Step is replacing the original data set with a new one.  All the information about indexes are lost in that replace.

Instead, use `PROC DATASETS` to modify the data set in place:

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
modify temp;
rename id=id_code;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: **Thank you so much!** This really solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Use MODIFY instead of SET.

```
DATA temp;
  MODIFY temp (RENAME=id=id_code);
RUN;
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  The rename is not supported with Modify and is ignored.  At least not on the version I have.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't know MODIFY was limited in a DATA step.  Strange that is doesn't give any notes, warnings or errors when this is run.

Comment: @DomPazz The RENAME data set option is NOT ignored, the PDV contains the RENAMED variable you can verify this with PUT \_ALL\_;
Id_Code=p amount=52 _ERROR_=0 _IORC_=0 _N_=1
This does not change the name in TEMP as you have noted.